# How to post relative to application root in jsp?

Tags: java, jsp, tomcat

I have a maven project which compiles into tryJEdit.war file.
When I copy this to tomcat folder and startup Tomcat, I can access the app from:

localhost:8080/tryJEdit

In index.jsp I have:

```
<form method="post" action="tugay">
```

So after the form is posted, I find myself on:

```
localhost:8080/tryJEdit/tugay -> Which is fine..
```

But when I change my form to:

```
<form method="post" action="/tugay">
```

I findmyself in:

```
localhost:8080/tugay
```

which is not good.

Is there anyway to get to localhost:8080/tryJEdit/tugay by telling something like:

```
<form method="post" action="$APPLICATION_ROOT/tugay">
```

in the jsp file?

**EDIT & EXTEND THE QUESTION**

In a servlet doGet method when I try:

```
ServletContext ctx = getServletContext();
InputStream is = ctx.getResourceAsStream("/re.pdf");
```

The file **re.pdf** is actually is searched in tryJEdit/re.pdf not localhost:8080/re.pdf , but for the case above if I post to /tugay then I end up in localhost:8080/tugay not tryJEdit/tugay ...

Regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html#getContextPath()

```
<form method="post" action="<%=request.getContextPath()%>/tugay">
```

Answer (score 1):

To do it without scriptlets, try

```
<form method="post" action="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/tugay">
```